# Can't figure out how to conditionally lag a variable

Tags: r

I am having problems creating a lagged variable that resets itself on two different conditions: 1) whether there is an onset of war (1 or a 0); 2) whether a country switches.

Here is example data (EDITED):

```
   year wartype war_onset country neighborWar
1  1970    <NA>         0      US           1
2  1971    <NA>         0      US           1
3  1972    <NA>         0      US           1
4  1973    <NA>         0      US           0
5  1974   civil         1      US           0
6  1975    <NA>         0      US           1
7  1976    <NA>         0      US           0
8  1970    <NA>         0     Rus           1
9  1971    <NA>         0     Rus           1
10 1972    <NA>         0     Rus           0
11 1973   civil         1     Rus           0
12 1974    <NA>         0     Rus           1
13 1975    <NA>         0     Rus           1
14 1976    <NA>         0     Rus           1
15 1977    <NA>         0     Rus           0
```

I want to create a lagged variable on neighbor war with the above conditioning so that the data looks like this (EDITED):

```
    year wartype war_onset country neighborWar ideal_lag_behavior
 1  1970    <NA>         0      US           1                 NA
 2  1971    <NA>         0      US           1                 NA
 3  1972    <NA>         0      US           1                 NA
 4  1973    <NA>         0      US           0                  3
 5  1974   civil         1      US           0                  2
 6  1975    <NA>         0      US           1                 NA
 7  1976    <NA>         0      US           0                 NA
 8  1970    <NA>         0     Rus           1                 NA
 9  1971    <NA>         0     Rus           1                 NA
 10 1972    <NA>         0     Rus           0                 NA
 11 1973   civil         1     Rus           0                  2
 12 1974    <NA>         0     Rus           1                 NA
 13 1975    <NA>         0     Rus           1                 NA
 14 1976    <NA>         0     Rus           1                 NA
 15 1977    <NA>         0     Rus           0                  3
```

Rather than this (EDITED):

```
  > df
   year wartype war_onset country neighborWar lagged_variable
1  1970    <NA>         0      US           1              NA
2  1971    <NA>         0      US           1              NA
3  1972    <NA>         0      US           1              NA
4  1973    <NA>         0      US           0               3
5  1974   civil         1      US           0               2
6  1975    <NA>         0      US           1               2
7  1976    <NA>         0      US           0               1
8  1970    <NA>         0     Rus           1               2
9  1971    <NA>         0     Rus           1               3
10 1972    <NA>         0     Rus           0               2
11 1973   civil         1     Rus           0               2
12 1974    <NA>         0     Rus           1               2
13 1975    <NA>         0     Rus           1               2 
14 1976    <NA>         0     Rus           1               3
15 1977    <NA>         0     Rus           0               3
```

Data generating code:

```
b <- c(1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977)
c <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "civil", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "civil", NA, NA, NA, NA)
d <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
s <- c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "Rus", "Rus", "Rus", "Rus", "Rus", "Rus", "Rus", "Rus")
v <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
v3 <- v + lag(v,1) + lag(v,2) + lag(v,3)
df <- data.frame(b,c,d,s,v,v3)
colnames(df) <-c("year", "wartype", "war_onset", "country", 
             "neighborWar", "lagged variable")
```

The lagged variable decomposed:

```
v <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
lag1 <- lag(v,1)
lag2 <- lag(v,2)
lag3 <- lag(v,3)
lags_plus_v <- v + lag(v,1) + lag(v,2) + lag(v,3)
df <- data.frame(v, lag1, lag2, lag3, lags_plus_v)
df

  v lag1 lag2 lag3 lags_plus_v
1  1   NA   NA   NA          NA
2  1    1   NA   NA          NA
3  1    1    1   NA          NA
4  0    1    1    1           3
5  0    0    1    1           2
6  1    0    0    1           2
7  0    1    0    0           1
8  1    0    1    0           2
9  1    1    0    1           3
10 0    1    1    0           2
11 0    0    1    1           2
12 1    0    0    1           2
13 1    1    0    0           2
14 1    1    1    0           3
15 0    1    1    1           3
```

Any ideas. I haven't.

I have tried the plm package and couldn't figure out any solutions. I have been slowly hacking away at Hadley Wickham's book Advanced R for ideas on generating a function but haven't put 2 and 2 together yet.

Comment: cumsum( war_onset | country_switch)

Comment: It was admittedly pseudocode and probably need to be wrapped with 'diff' before it can be lagged.

Comment: I am sorry, but could you give an example. I am really new to time series in R (and somewhat in R) and am having a hard time understanding your recommendations.

Comment: So the immediate task is not lagging a dual condition, but rather just lagging  some sort of "switching-indicator" driven by `neighborWar` and doing this within the country? If so, I cannot figure out the rule for making the indicator equal to "2". Also clarify what it means to say that a "country switches"? And do expalin whether  "years" are supposed to be considered consecutive if they are in the row immediately after another year.

Comment: Your way of putting it is absolutely right, the lagging is dependent upon the "switching-indicator" and `neighborWar` is the variable that is to be lagged (i.e., `neighborWar + lag(neighborWar, 1) + lag(neighborWar, 2) + lag(neighborWar, 3)). I see it as there being two switching indicators: 1) for when there is an onset of war (so a switch from 0 to 1) and from a change in country (so from US to Russia).  The "2" is nothing more than the additive value of the lagged variables. Years is supposed to be consecutive (I have edited the question and data to reflect that, my apologies on that one).

Comment: I still do not understand the line-by-line rules for constructing 'ideal_lag_behavior'. The edit function is much to be desired over using comments in clarifying ambiguities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this produces what you are looking for, but it was a bit tricky to figure this out. Please try to be more explicit about the desired behavior (and the reasoning for it) in future questions.

The main point was to create a (lagged) grouping variable from `war_onset`.

I group the data by `country` and by the newly generated variable `x`. `x` equals the first lag of the cumulative sum of `war_onset`. I'll add a version of the sample data including the `x` variable to show what it looks like. Then, the rest is easily computed based on the description in the sample - it is the sum of `neighborWar` and the first 3 lags of the same variable. The values are `NA` whenever any of the lags of `neighborWar` is also NA.

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(country, x = lag(cumsum(war_onset), 1, default = 0)) %>%
  mutate(lagged_variable = neighborWar + lag(neighborWar,1) + lag(neighborWar,2) + lag(neighborWar,3)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-x)

#Source: local data frame [15 x 6]
#
#   year wartype war_onset country neighborWar lagged_variable
#1  1970    <NA>         0      US           1              NA
#2  1971    <NA>         0      US           1              NA
#3  1972    <NA>         0      US           1              NA
#4  1973    <NA>         0      US           0               3
#5  1974   civil         1      US           0               2
#6  1975    <NA>         0      US           1              NA
#7  1976    <NA>         0      US           0              NA
#8  1970    <NA>         0     Rus           1              NA
#9  1971    <NA>         0     Rus           1              NA
#10 1972    <NA>         0     Rus           0              NA
#11 1973   civil         1     Rus           0               2
#12 1974    <NA>         0     Rus           1              NA
#13 1975    <NA>         0     Rus           1              NA
#14 1976    <NA>         0     Rus           1              NA
#15 1977    <NA>         0     Rus           0               3
```

---

For demonstration of the grouping variable `x` and the lags of neighborWar, here's an example showing all the columns:

```
df %>%
  group_by(country, x = lag(cumsum(war_onset), 1, default = 0)) %>%
  mutate(lag1 =  lag(neighborWar,1),
         lag2 =  lag(neighborWar,2),
         lag3 =  lag(neighborWar,3),
         lagged_variable = neighborWar + lag1 + lag2 + lag3)

#Source: local data frame [15 x 10]
#Groups: country, x
#
#   year wartype war_onset country neighborWar x lag1 lag2 lag3 lagged_variable
#1  1970    <NA>         0      US           1 0   NA   NA   NA              NA
#2  1971    <NA>         0      US           1 0    1   NA   NA              NA
#3  1972    <NA>         0      US           1 0    1    1   NA              NA
#4  1973    <NA>         0      US           0 0    1    1    1               3
#5  1974   civil         1      US           0 0    0    1    1               2
#6  1975    <NA>         0      US           1 1   NA   NA   NA              NA
#7  1976    <NA>         0      US           0 1    1   NA   NA              NA
#8  1970    <NA>         0     Rus           1 1   NA   NA   NA              NA
#9  1971    <NA>         0     Rus           1 1    1   NA   NA              NA
#10 1972    <NA>         0     Rus           0 1    1    1   NA              NA
#11 1973   civil         1     Rus           0 1    0    1    1               2
#12 1974    <NA>         0     Rus           1 2   NA   NA   NA              NA
#13 1975    <NA>         0     Rus           1 2    1   NA   NA              NA
#14 1976    <NA>         0     Rus           1 2    1    1   NA              NA
#15 1977    <NA>         0     Rus           0 2    1    1    1               3
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks for putting up with my opaque question and slogging an answer out. Bonded dust was trying to get me to see the cumsum thing too, it didn't make sense until I saw here.